# How do I have different desktops on two monitors?

Tags: windows, monitor

In windows 10 home I want to use 2 monitors with 1 or 2 desktops.
As when we use extent 1 monitor has the desktop icons and the other has only the taskbar and we can only drag the things to that screen.
Is that possible that I can give the whole access to both of the monitors?

Answer (score 1):

Quick Answer - No.
You cannot (as of right now) run two virtual desktops on two screens.

But, with a quick Google search I have found some 3rd party solutions that can virtualize this feature.

Other than that - you can Right click on the Taskbar and enter to Taskbar Settings - there you can find a few other Settings (for both the taskbar and the icons) that might help you achieve something close to you original request.